# Color coding plot

Tags: r, plot, colors, point

I have made this plot:

```
plot(prey$snake.SVL, prey$prey.weight, col = prey$snake.id, pch = 20, cex = 2)
```

This plot shows the SVL(length of snake)VS prey weight pr.snake.id:

[image]

The problem is how do I get a color for each snake?

Comment: Set `palette(rainbow(length(unique(prey$snake.id))))` before plotting. I think `palette("default")` has just 8 colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = snake.svl, aes(x = snake.svl,y = prey.weight, col = snake.id)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

ggplot might be the better bet for plotting.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(snake.svl,aes(x=snake.svl,y=prey.weight))+geom_point(aes(color=snake.id))
```

That may not be exactly correct but it should help you start out.

The main point is that ggplot and geom_point will give you what you want.